# Extracting from URL - Long URL

Tags: javascript, url

I'm currently trying to extract from ReturnUrl= ... I want to extract the URL from the link below using javascript. Can anyone help?

```
http://testdealbuilderCCMS/questionnaire.aspx?db_template_reference=Construction: Westfield Services Agreement&ContractDescription=Facilities Contract&NatureServices=FACILITIES&SiteDescription=Retail Units&ThirdPartyAgreementsList=&ServiceFee=1000&ReturnUrl=http://localhost:4965&launcher.aspx?directLink=PX&caseKey=7ccef65756504a79bc3a4a6687c0d9555e519ec9079241c9944c6a523704&PXid=
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: `var extractedUrl = originalUrl.replace( /&ReturnUrl=([^&#]+)(&#|$)/, "$1" )` would be the method by the book. However, that assumes that all occurrences of `&,#` in the ReturnUrl  parameter are properly percent-encoded ( `%26`, `%23` ), but they typically aren't. Do you have more information about the structure of ReturnUrl and the embedding url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are lots of edge cases here that will make this fail. So be careful, use this only if your string **always ends with the ReturnURL parameter**.

Find the position of the `ReturnURL=` in the string then get the substring from `ReturnURL=` position + `ReturnURL=` length, to the end.

http://jsfiddle.net/3hvajedg/1/

```
the_string = 'http://testdealbuilderCCMS/questionnaire.aspx?db_template_reference=Construction: Westfield Services Agreement&ContractDescription=Facilities Contract&NatureServices=FACILITIES&SiteDescription=Retail Units&ThirdPartyAgreementsList=&ServiceFee=1000&ReturnUrl=http://localhost:4965&launcher.aspx?directLink=PX&caseKey=7ccef65756504a79bc3a4a6687c0d9555e519ec9079241c9944c6a523704&PXid=';

alert(the_string.substring((the_string.indexOf('ReturnUrl=')+'ReturnUrl='.length)));
```